# How to install CREBS on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, crebs

I tried installing [CREBS](http://www.obfuscatepenguin.net/crebs) on Ubuntu 14.04. unfortunately the repository installation doesn't work, so I decided to download the source code. But after following their instructions(namely running setup.sh as root) I get this error when typing "crebs" in a terminal:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/crebs", line 38, in <module>
    from crebs.main import main
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/crebs/lib/crebs/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gtk                import glade
ImportError: cannot import name glade
```

any hint? thank you

Comment: It seems that you are missing a dependency. Check if you have glade library installed: `sudo apt-get install python-glade2` then try to run it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a dependency.

You can try to install the glade library using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```